# Multiple ImageView on screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I want make an app on which want to display multiple images using imageviewer but only one image is displayed on screen at a time & second image comes using click of button, I want this because want to put animation when image comes on screen. Here i have tried viewpager which swipes the images. Is it possible in using viewpager we can put animation on each images when it comes on screen.

This is my code of complete activity

```
public class Numbers extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer BG;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        BG.setLooping(true);
        BG.setVolume(100, 100);
        BG.start();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[0]);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BG.pause();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BG.start();
    }

    private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,
                                     R.raw.two,
                                     R.raw.three,
                                     R.raw.four,
                                     R.raw.five,
                                     R.raw.six,
                                     R.raw.seven,
                                     R.raw.eight,
                                     R.raw.nine,
                                     R.raw.ten};

    private int imageArra[] =  {R.drawable.no1,
                                R.drawable.no2,
                                R.drawable.no3,
                                R.drawable.no4,
                                R.drawable.no5,
                                R.drawable.no6,
                                R.drawable.no7,
                                R.drawable.no8,
                                R.drawable.no9,
                                R.drawable.no10};

    public  OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
        {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[arg1]);
        mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.numbers, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please suggest me tutorials or solution for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out below code to provide animation on `ViewPager`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 6000, seconds * 1000); // delay
                                                    // in milliseconds
}

// this is an inner class...
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // As the TimerTask run on a seprate thread from UI thread we have
        // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            myPager.setCurrentItem(myPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

            }
        });

    }
}

 myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            Log.e("pageselectrd", "selected:" + String.valueOf(arg0));
            timer.cancel();
            pageSwitcher(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: @GrlsHu how do i add button controller to swipe page??

Comment: What kind of controller ?

Comment: @GrlsHU like next button & previous button

Comment: You need to add the buttons in your adapter layout to manage the next and previous buttons.